# If condition inside jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
$(function() {
var services = [      
  "Water Wash",
  "Tyre Puncture"      
];
var servicesCar = [      
  "Car Wash",
  "Tyre Puncture",
  "Vehicle Diagonstics",
  "Other Repairs",
];
$('#ServiceType').autocomplete({
    if($('#VehicleType').val() == '4w') {
        source: servicesCar,
        minLength: 0,
        scroll: true
   }
  else {
        source: services,
        minLength: 0,
        scroll: true
    } }).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
});
```

I need to check whether the option value is `2w` or `4w` and based on that value, I should display the source tags. But, this code is not autocompleting the input

```
<select id="VehicleType" name="VehicleType">
  <option value="2w"> Bike </option> 
  <option value="4w"> Car </option> 
</select>
```

Here is my HTML code

Comment: Please mention the issue you encountered

Comment: @AnoopLL It is not autocompleting with an `if` condition inside it, Whereas, I need to check the condition and then send source tags

Comment: you need to write the autocomplete code inside the onChange of vehicle type.

Comment: I don't need to call autocomplete on changing the option. I just have to take the current value being selected and send tags based upon that @AnoopLL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select id="VehicleType" name="VehicleType">
  <option value="2w"> Bike </option> 
  <option value="4w"> Car </option> 
</select>

<input type="text" id="ServiceType" />
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
var services = [      
  "Water Wash",
  "Tyre Puncture"      
];
var servicesCar = [      
  "Car Wash",
  "Tyre Puncture",
  "Vehicle Diagonstics",
  "Other Repairs",
];

$( "#ServiceType" ).focusin(function() {
        if($('#VehicleType').val() == '4w') {
                $('#ServiceType').autocomplete({
            source: servicesCar,
            minLength: 0,
            scroll: true
        });        
   }
  else {
            $('#ServiceType').autocomplete({
            source: services,
            minLength: 0,
            scroll: true
        });  
    }    
        });
});
```

Reference [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/49/)